# pyMongo nested divide, gt

Tags: python, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a document with a field "disk" as such:

```
"host": "localhost"
"disk":[
                {
                    "dir": "/var",
                    "capacity": 6291456,
                    "used": 291456
                },
                {
                    "dir": "/tmp",
                    "capacity": 6291456,
                    "used": 1365386
                }
            ]
```

I am trying to write a query to select servers where the percent used is greater than 90%. I need to nest the gt and divide functions but I can't get it to work.

Essentially it needs to be:

```
for item in disk:
    if used/capacity > .9:
        return document
```

I have tried:

```
db.servers.find({ 'disk': { '$elemMatch' : { '$expr': { '$gt' : [{'$divide': {'used': 'capacity'}}, 0]  } } } })
```

with the gt value set to 0 so it should return everything just for testing but it is returning nothing.

What is the right syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `$filter` operator in `$expr` expression. You can't use query operator (`$elemMatch`) in $expr. `$expr` only allows aggregation operators.

Outer `$gt` to check when `$size` of matching records is greater than 0

Something like

```
db.servers.find(
{"$expr":{
  "$gt":[
    {"$size":{
      "$filter":{
        "input":"$disk",
        "as":"item",
        "cond":{
          "$gt":[
            {"$divide":["$$item.used","$$item.capacity"]},
            0.9
          ]
        }
      }
    }},
    0
  ]
}})
```